# How to modify Social media sharing thumbnail grid?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, open-graph-protocol, social-sharing-buttons

I am not a SEO guy, but desperately finding an answer in web without any clue. How can I make this kind of Social media sharing view
[image]

instead of this

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="hello.xyz" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="Full Stack Developer" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="A full stack web application develoepr who sometimes dines suger in his tea !" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="https://wqfkv1ient.sharedwithexpose.com/assets/images/profile02-og.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name"          content="Full Stack Developer">
<meta property="og:locale"             content="en_US">
<meta property="fb:profile_id"         content="xxxxxx">
```

But it's making the second(wider one) preview. This is maybe something very basic. But I really in need of this preview.

Comment: Which social site?  Is this on Facebook?

Comment: Yeah. I am trying it in Facebook sharing debugger. I also need it in Linkedin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a very small image - the sharing thumbnail has to do with the size of the image/aspect ratio and can be very inconsistent.

For Facebook the rule is to use a minimum of `600x315px` to display the *large image format*, so with that we can deduce what will work to get the small version with image will floating left and the description on the right like you want.

To control for various platforms and consistency, I would make `og:image` less than or equal to `400x400` with a square aspect ratio. The width is probably the most important part tho, so `400x300` is likely safe too.

You can also specify dimensions too (via [Open Graph](https://ogp.me/)):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="A shiny red apple with a bite taken out" />
```

This specifies the image dimensions to the crawler so that it can render the image immediately without having to asynchronously download and process it.

Your description should be less than or equal to 200px.

Comment: That's working for facebook! However it's not working for LinkedIn. I made the image dimension 400 x 400.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

It's suggesting the image dimension should be 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels. So to be consistent with both linkedin and facebook ?

Comment: That'll give you the larger thumbnail with text on a strip beneath. Try going smaller than 400px wide for Linkedin, if it doesn't work keep decreasing size. @OsmanRafi

Comment: Also try the 400x300 ratio for LinkedIn